# Using camera in processing for moving in specific area

Tags: java, processing

Hi I'm a new coder on processing. I have long and complex code but  I prepared a simple code to you for my question.

```
float camX = 0;
float camY = 0;
float camZ = (height/2)/tan(PI/6) - 260;

float x, y, z = 0;

float rotX = 0, rotY = 0;
float lastX, lastY;
float distX, distY;

void setup() {
  size(1600, 1000, P3D);
}


void draw() {
  background(0);

  camera(camX, camY, camZ, //default camera position without 360 degree
    x, y, z, //where it is looking to
    0, 1, 0); //eye openness

  rotateX(rotX + distY);
  rotateY(rotY + distX);

  beginShape(QUADS);
  vertex(-350, 100.1, 350);      // Upper left to Corner     
  vertex(350, 100.1, 350);       // Upper right to Corner
  vertex(350, 100.1, -350);      // Bottom right to Corner
  vertex(-350, 100.1, -350);     // Bottom left to Corner
  endShape();

  if (keyPressed)
  {
    if (key == 'w') {           // GO FRONT
      camZ += 5;
    } else if (key == 's') {    // GO BACK
      camZ -= 5;
    } else if (key == 'a') {    // GO LEFT
      camX += 5;
      x += 5;
    } else if (key == 'd') {    // GO RIGHT
      camX -=5;
      x -= 5;
    }
  }
}

public void mousePressed() {
  lastX = mouseX;
  lastY = mouseY;
}

public void mouseDragged() {
  distX = radians(mouseX - lastX);
  distY = radians(lastY - mouseY);
}

public void mouseReleased() {
  rotX += distY; 
  rotY += distX;
  distX = distY = 0;
}
```

So, I want to make a camera that can only go around the vertices of which was given.The camera won't go outside from the white area. How to make that happened? Also there is a bug when I go further on the area. The camera changes the way when it reachs the half of the area. Can you help me about fixing that bug? Thank you.

Comment: Can you please rephrase your question ? What do you mean by making the camera only going inside the 4 vertices ? Do you mean getting the camera to look directly at the quad ?

Comment: Of course. No, I mean the camera will stay on the white area and can't go outside from that area.I edited. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately I am unable to provide a detailed answer, but I'd advise looking at other FPS camera implementations (e.g. [QuesyCam](https://github.com/jrc03c/queasycam), [FPCamera](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q2uJkLxxGbM), etc.). Once that works reliably, [`constrain()`](https://processing.org/reference/constrain_.html)ing the player's position within the -350,350 bounds should be easy.

Comment: Thanks @GeorgeProfenza I tried QuesyCam and FPCamera. They work great in an example but, it is so hard to implement to my code. However, you are right for the secod idea. It is much easier just control the player's position. Thank you.